# JavaScript Linking drop down menu to checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I am trying to link my HTML drop down menu to my table which has checkboxes in it.

This javascript function is trying to see if the "arc" value has been selected then disable the checkbox 3 which shows spectral:

```
function showShields()
{
if (document.getElementById("Shield").value == ("arc")
{
document.getElementById("checkBox3").disabled=true;
}
}
```

This is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<script src="SpiritShield.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>What kind of shield are you interested in?</p>
<select id="Shield">
   <option value="arc">ARC</option>
   <option value="divine">GAS</option>
   <option value="spectral">MIG</option>
   <option value="elysian">ANY</option>
</select>
</body>
<table border="2" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
   <th>Checkbox</th>
   <th>Shield</th>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkBox1"</td>
   <td>ARC1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkBox2"</td>
   <td>ARC2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkBox3"</td>
   <td>SPECTRAL1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkBox4"</td>
<td>SPECTRAL2</td>
</tr>
</table>

</html>
```

Could someone help me solve this?

Thank you

Comment: In your HTML is invalid, there are some unclosed tags.

Comment: Hmm where? Plus I dont think thats the reason why my javascript function isnt working :(

Comment: Muthu is right, your /body tag is after your select, you should move it to the bottom before /html.

Comment: Oh thanks I just realised. But it does not work however still :O

Comment: @Gary `<input>` tags are not closed. `<body>` tags is closed somewhere

Comment: Hmm the input tags are missing something? Could someone try the code with it all fixed. So when the arc option is selected. The checkbox3 is disabled. Thanks

Does not seem to be working for me.

Comment: It worked fine for me when all I did was copy your code and move the function into the script tags rather than referencing the external js file. I have fixed the unclosed tags and it works fine for me in both Chrome and IE9.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, although I did notice a missing parenthesis in the if condition:

```
function showShields()
{
if (document.getElementById("Shield").value == ("arc")) //your missing missing parenthesis was here
{
document.getElementById("checkBox3").disabled=true;
}
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. The above still does not work unfortunately. When I choose ARC from the drop down menu the checkbox isnt disabled in the table. :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Hpcsq/2/

```
function showShields(what)
    {
    if (what.value == ("arc"))
        {
        document.getElementById("checkBox3").checked=false;
        }
    }​

<!DOCTYPE html>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<script src="SpiritShield.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>What kind of shield are you interested in?</p>
<select id="Shield" onchange="showShields(this)">
       <option value="arc">---</option>
   <option value="arc">ARC</option>
   <option value="divine">GAS</option>
   <option value="spectral">MIG</option>
   <option value="elysian">ANY</option>
</select>
</body>
<table border="2" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
   <th>Checkbox</th>
   <th>Shield</th>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkBox1"</td>
   <td>ARC1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkBox2"</td>
   <td>ARC2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkBox3" checked="checked"></td>
   <td>SPECTRAL1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkBox4"</td>
<td>SPECTRAL2</td>
</tr>
</table>

</html>​
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. That code just ticks the box, I would like it to disable to the checkbox so the user is unable to click it.

Comment: I have updated the code, check it again. I had interpreted your code wrong ;-)

Comment: Ok thanks but it not doesnt work lol. Coul you try the code with the js to see if it works. So when the arc option is selected the table should automatically disable the checkbox 3. Ta

Comment: Oh ok I just tried it on there, when i chose the ARC option the button is clickable, does that happen with yours?

Comment: Oh dont worry I fixed it. Thanks